# Testing Music Library in the iPhone emulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, emulation, ipod

I'd like to be able to debug my application in the iPhone emulator. The app uses the Media Library Framework so I'm not really sure whether I'm able to add songs to the emulator and actually try out the app there. Is this possible?

Right now I'm just using the iPod directly for this...

Thanks,
rui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's impossible at this point.

Source: my knowledge from developing apps based on MediaPlayer.framework since May of '09.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation mate!